# How to 'break' the general instruction of `\beamerdefaultoverlayspecification{<+-1|alert@+>}`?

Tags: beamer, itemize, presentations

How to 'break' the general instruction of `\beamerdefaultoverlayspecification{<+-1|alert@+>}`?

```
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{test}

\setbeamertemplate{itemize items}[circle]
\begin{itemize}
\item first
\end{itemize}


\end{frame}
```

As is the code above, the command `\beamerdefaultoverlayspecification{<+-1|alert@+>}` makes every item to appear when one clicks

And it's fine except that there is one *itemize environment* which I would like to not to have that 'display style'.

How can I do that?

Help me please.

Comment: What exactly is the style you are looking for? The overlay specifications can be determined as an optional argument after many environments in `beamer`. For itemize, you can write `\begin{itemize}<specifications you want>`

Comment: Please stop throwing code fragments at us, but add small, but compilable documents to your questions. See [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) for more information.

Comment: @samcarter sorry, I did ask the question quickly and I forgot about it again. Seems like I just forgot the \end{documment} and the \documentclass{beamer}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a local overlay specification (between `[]`) to individual environments or items. The specification for *show always* is `<*>`. MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\beamerdefaultoverlayspecification{<+->}
\setbeamertemplate{itemize items}[circle]

\begin{frame}{first test}
\begin{itemize} % using the default overlay specification
\item first
\item second
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{second test}
\begin{itemize}[<*>] % all items always visible
\item next first
\item next second
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Another approach could be to redefine the default overlay specifications within a group, this way the changed definition will only affect lists which are within this group:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\beamerdefaultoverlayspecification{<+-1|alert@+>} 

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{test}

\begingroup
\beamerdefaultoverlayspecification{} 
\begin{itemize}
\item first
\end{itemize}
\endgroup

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```